Three-phase IGBT inverter - Switching Loss Model
I aim to model the switching losses in a three-phase IGBT inverter controlled using Space Vector Modulation (SVM). I intend to use the approximated formula found in this paper, equal to:
$$P_{sw}={1\over \pi}(e_{on}+e_{off}+e_{rrl})f_{C}V_{dc}I_{m}$$,
obtained under the assumption of a balanced system, where: $$I_{m^{=}}\sqrt{i_{u^{2}}+i_{v^{2}}+i_{w^{2}}}$$
\$V_{dc}\$ and \$I_{m}\$ are used because \$e_{on},e_{off},e_{rrl}\$ are normalized values and represent respectively the energy dissipation during turn-on, turn-off (IGBT) and reverse recovery (diode).
I am uncertain about the multiplication factor of \${1\over \pi}\$ in the formula. If the intention is to use the average current, the factor should be \${2\over \pi}\$. Also in this accessible document they use factor \${1\over \pi}\$ (page 5).
Moreover, based on my understanding of SVM, switching occurs between \$v_i\$, \$v_{i+1}\$ and either \$v_0\$ or \$v_7\$. This is illustrated in the provided graph, where in each case, the state of only one pair of IGBTs changes.

Given this, why should I multiply \$P_{sw}\$ by 6 (the number of couples IGBT-diode), as the paper suggests, to calculate the total power loss, since from what I understand, per each step, only one pair of IGBTs switches state?

Since the paper claims to be an "experimental evaluation" they may have some inconsistencies in the equations. If you explain what $e_{on}+e_{off}+e_{rrl}$ stands for (or give a link without a pay-wall) we could investigate it further. (The intention of SE is that questions are self-contained, or at least understandable through accessible links.)

I am sorry about this, I edited the question. Thank you

In the 2nd document link, Fig. 5 on page 4 explains the losses \$E_\text{ON}\$ and \$E_\text{OFF}\$. These depend on the current and voltage just before and after the switching. If we call those \$I_\text{NOM}\$ and \$V_\text{NOM}\$, then it all seems to be consistent. If all switching actions are for these current and voltage values, we can use \$E_\text{ON}\$ and \$E_\text{OFF}\$ without any scaling or re-defining, only multiplying by the switching freq \$f_\text{SW}\$. We then get:
$$
 P_\text{ SW(IGBT)} = (E_\text{ON}+E_\text{OFF}) * f_\text{SW}  \tag{1}
$$
But this is not the case, the real situation is Fig. 7 on page 5. The switching frequency \$f_\text{SW}\$ seems to be around 40 or 50 times the mains frequency, and not all switching actions take place with the same current. In fact half of the mains cycle seems to be a dead zone for each IGBT, and during the other half the current varies more or less like a half sine wave, so on average the current at the moment of switching is \$1/\pi\$ times the current at the "maximum" switching moments. But also for those maximum switching moments, our application probably has
different current and voltage values than the \$I_\text{NOM}\$ and \$V_\text{NOM}\$ from the datasheet that were used to define \$E_\text{ON}\$ and \$E_\text{OFF}\$.
If we assume that the losses scale proportional to the voltage and also proportional to the current, we can correct things by:

multiplying by the ratios of the current and voltage in our application with those used to define the losses in the datasheet (values at "maximum" switching moments should be used).
dividing by \$\pi\$ because on average the current is that much lower than the value at the maximum switching moments (or maybe it's a combination of lower current and lower voltage, but in any case the average for the switching loss is that much lower, acc. to Fig. 7).

This gives:
$$
 P_\text{ SW(IGBT)} = \frac{(E_\text{ON}+E_\text{OFF}) * f_\text{SW}}{\pi}
 * \frac{I_\text{pk}}{I_\text{NOM}} * \frac{V_\text{DC Link}}{V_\text{NOM}}   \tag{2}
$$
and that is what we find on page 5.

Thank you a lot for your help. Now I understand.
Regarding your last point, I do not think that the division by $\pi$ comes from a combination of lower current and lower voltage, but as you mentioned earlier, it results from calculating the average over a period of the current, which is a half sinusoid.

Indeed. But since I don't know the precise circuit, and Fig. 7 only shows the power as a (more or less) half sine wave, I can only guess that the current is responsible for this shape, which would be the case if switching is always between the same voltage levels, as it will be in many circuits...
